# Adding elements to two different arrays, changing between them

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to add elements into two different arrays, changing between the arrays.

For example:

```
Input: 1
Input: 2
Input: 3
Input: 4
Input: 5
Input: 6

Array1 = [1, 3, 5]
Array2 = [2, 4, 6]
```

Any help/code would be appreciated.

Comment: `if (inputNumber % 2 != 0)
    // add to array 1
else
    // add to array 2`

If the inputs are as you displayed it..

Comment: I want 2 arrays to be formed, not just 1. Why else System.out.println("The number is odd.")?

Comment: Look at my reworked comment...

Another possibility would be:

`if (Array1.size() <= Array2.size())  /* add to array 1 */ else /* add to array 2 */`

Comment: I have added some more detail to my question, inc code. Hope that helps explain my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
int[] ar1=new int[3];
int[] ar2=new int[3];

int evenIndex=0;
int oddIndex=0;
for(int i=0;i<ar1.length+ar2.length;i++){
    System.out.println("Enter number");
    int num=input.nextInt();

    if(i%2==0)// if the index is even number
    {
        ar1[evenIndex]=num;
        evenIndex++;
    }
    else{

        ar2[oddIndex]=num;
        oddIndex++;
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<ar1.length;i++)//print the result of array1
    System.out.print(ar1[i]+" ");

System.out.println();

for(int i=0;i<ar2.length;i++)//print the result of array2
    System.out.print(ar2[i]+" ");
```

Example:

```
Enter number
1
Enter number
2
Enter number
3
Enter number
4
Enter number
5
Enter number
6

1 3 5 
2 4 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple: you created TWO arrays of size N.

But when you intend to put N/2 elements into the first array, and N/2 elements into the other, then both your arrays should have length N/2.

In other words: your arrays of length N are preset with 0 values. You put values into every second slot, and the others stay 0.

Comment: Thanks ever so much for your help!